# Force SCNView to use OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, scenekit, metal

When using Xcode 7 and creating a new SceneKit OS X project, it seems to default to using Metal for the SCNView.

If I try to do this after creating a new Game project in Xcode 7:

var context = gameView.context

The result is nil. The view is using Metal and not OpenGL.

However, creating the same in Xcode 6.4, the context exists like expected.

How can I force my SCNView to use OpenGL and not Metal?

Comment: This is a good thing to know but it's not the solution you should be asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an SCNView, you have an option to set the renderer in the initialiser:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNView/initWithFrame:options:

These are the options you have available, Metal or OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.0 will likely come later):

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SCNRenderingAPI

So setting to SCNRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 will get you what you want, a forcibly OpenGL ES 2.0 rendered SceneKit View

Comment: Why would you think OpenGL ES 3.0 support is likely? I don't think Apple has any incentive to support it.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. I was looking at the OS X api's (which don't contain the 10.11 API changes).

There's also a dropdown menu for Rendering API available for SCNView in Interface Builder.

Comment: Is this how it is supposed to be set: `SCNView(frame: view.bounds, options: ["preferredRenderingAPI": SCNRenderingAPI.openGLES2])` because it's not working for me :(

Comment: @Guig  haven't tried lately. I was ignored, until very recently, when reporting on rendering issues with SceneKit to Apple. So I kind of lost interest in dealing with the intricacies of its many problems. It's not a work-in-progress. At its best, SceneKit is a statement of intent that's fast getting neglected... by Apple. I expect they'll discard it in a couple of iOS versions, and release a Metal based engine for both 2D and 3D. With equally dismal support and updates.

Comment: Yeah I've run into a number of issues with SceneKit and the new iOS 10 that are hard to believe...

Comment: If anyone is still searching, the correct way to initialize with OpenGL in Swift 3 is: `SCNView(frame: frame, options: [SCNView.Option.preferredRenderingAPI.rawValue: NSNumber(value: SCNRenderingAPI.openGLES2.rawValue)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with code below

```
let scnView = SCNView(frame: .zero, options: [SCNView.Option.preferredRenderingAPI.rawValue : NSNumber(value: SCNRenderingAPI.openGLES2.rawValue)])
```